# 3D fantasy game

Tags: game, windows-xp

I need suggestions for a 3D fantasy game.

Specs:

- Windows XP SP 3
- Pentium D 3.0 ghz
- 1 GB RAM
- ATI Radeon X200 inbuild 128MB
- DirectX 9 support
- Plenty of free hard disk space

Seems this question isn't a fit for this platform but relatively good fantasy stuff you played pre 2005-2006 etc. Google searches turned wild and wide.

Single player offline

Cost : anything

Comment: You have to be more specific about what kind of game you are looking for. How should the gameplay be? Perspective? Single/multiplayer? How much may it cost?

Comment: You may want to have a look at [The Witcher 1](https://www.gog.com/game/the_witcher)